# Can I use Android Studio, and Eclipse for the same project?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

Android Studio is still in preview, however many projects are already using Gradle build system which is integrated into Android Studio.

Being an early access preview however, migrating a whole project to Android Studio is too risky, and migration seems to be a one way process.

Is there a way for a single Android project to work seamlessly in both environments (IDEs: Eclipse, Android Studio; and build systems: Ant, Gradle)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set your build.gradle in android studio like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

But I suggest to use Android Studio. I use it from 0.3.6 and I find it easier to use than Eclipse.
I've made Apps with native lib, modules and the only problem I've found was that **strings.xml** was reformatted after create a new Activity.